# Submit form information multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

I have a form with a multiple select option in it. I wanted to make it so that when the user hits submit, it will populate my DB with all the relevant fields, then go through some sort of loop for the multiple select portion.

https://jsfiddle.net/vtyofmza/1/

Example would be someone highlights 3 fields in the multiple select and puts in their name. When they hit submit, the database would populate

John Doe - Breakfast

John Doe - Snacks

John Doe - Dessert

I was thinking something like this might work, but it just resets the form all over again

```
iSelect = $('#meal').val();
iLength = $('#meal option:selected').length;
for (i = 0; i < iLength; i++){
    $('#meal').val(iSelect[i])
    document.form.submit();
}
```

But when it submits the information, it goes back and resets the page all over again.

The submit.cfm looks like this

```
<cfquery name="Add" datasource="food"> 
INSERT INTO Log (Meal, Name)
VALUES (#Form.Neal#, #Form.Name#)
</cfquery>
<cflocation url="... loops back to original page">
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with this in javascript, just accept the field value in coldfusion and process it there.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in depth regarding that?

Comment: @khgove - As Kevin said, javascript's job is to submit the entered form values. Any looping should be done in ColdFusion. Multiple select list values will be submitted as a csv list ie , ie form.Meal = "Breakfast,Snacks,Dessert". Simply [loop](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfloop%3A+looping+over+a+list%2C+a+file%2C+or+an+array) through that list and execute an `insert` for each meal + name.  Having said that, typically your list "value" would be some sort of numeric id, rather than text (which may have issues if the text contains the list delimiter).

Comment: In case the above is not just psuedo-code, remember to use cfqueryparam in the real query to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @Leigh, could you show me how this loop would be done? I'm not exceptional at SQL and I mainly only use it to query and insert. In the meantime i'll trial and error it.
Also, yes, this is all pseudo, my main code is significantly different. This was just a fast concept to show what I was trying to do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Kevin B said above, this is not a job for javascript. Any extra handling or looping should be done in ColdFusion.

**Basic Loop:**

Multiple selections will be submitted as a csv list ie `form.Meal = "Breakfast,Snacks,Dessert"`. Simply loop through that list and execute an insert for each meal + name. There are ways to improve this kind of looping, but below is the basic idea (no validation):

```
<!--- ensure field always exists --->
<cfparam name="form.Meal" default="">

<!--- loop through the meal list and insert each one individually --->
<cfloop list="#form.Meal#" index="currMealName">
    <cfquery name="Add" datasource="food"> 
       INSERT INTO Log (Meal, Name)
       VALUES ( 
         <cfqueryparam value="#currMealName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        , <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
       )
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

**NB:** A few important notes

- These kind of related query loops should be wrapped in a single [transaction](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cftransaction) to ensure data integrity
- Typically the list "value" would be some sort of numeric id, rather than text (which may have issues if the text contains the list delimiter).

**Better Option**

If the source of the select list values is another database table, another approach is to use a `SELECT` statement to insert the values. This has the advantage of built in validation and it also inserts all of the values in a single query.  Personally, I prefer that approach rather than looping. For demo purposes, the example uses type=cf_sql_varchar. Obviously update the types as needed to match your actual columns.

```
INSERT INTO Log (Meal, Name)
SELECT Meal
      , <cfqueryparam value="#form.name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
FROM  YourMealTable
WHERE  Meal IN 
          (
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.meal#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
          )
```